# How can I pass variable into function when the script text on prams

Tags: javascript

```
 function domHTML(script, contact = {}, user = {}) {
console.log(contact.first_name);
console.log(user.name);
let dom = `
  <div class="main py-3 w-100">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    ${script}
    </div>  
   </div>
  </div>`;
console.log(dom);
//return dom;}



let script = `Hey ${contact.first_name}, ${contact.first_name} this is ${user.name} giving you a quick call from the benefits office here in ${contact.state}. I’ll have you have the phone here sec but they have me giving you a quick call because of a form you filled out requesting more information about the life insurance programs through the state of ${contact.state}. They have me, the field underwriter, calling to verify the information, I have DOB as ${contact.birthday} is that correct? Perfect, so ${contact.first_name} like I said I’m just the field underwriter they have calling to let you know your request has been processed.
```

We’re doing everything virtually now due to covid. Takes about 10-15 min to get you the info. Grab a pen and paper for notes and will knock this out so you don’t get any more calls.`

I want to do every variable will be replaced with  function arguments

Comment: Please edit your query properly with proper description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your `script` into a function that accepts arguments and pass it to `domHTML`, that way `script` function can get the variables of `contact` and `user` passed to it.

```js
function domHTML(fn ,contact = {}, user = {}) {
    let theScript = fn(contact, user)
    let dom = `
  <div class="main py-3 w-100">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    ${theScript}
    </div>  
   </div>
  </div>`;
    return dom;
}

function script(contact, user){
    return `Hey ${contact.first_name}, ${contact.first_name} this is ${user.name} giving you a quick call from the benefits office here in ${contact.state}.
I’ll have you have the phone here sec but they have me giving you a quick call because of a form you filled out requesting more information about the life insurance programs through the state of ${contact.state}.
 They have me, the field underwriter, calling to verify the information, 
 I have DOB as ${contact.birthday} is that correct? Perfect, 
 so ${contact.first_name} like I said I’m just the field underwriter they have calling to let you know your request has been processed.`
}

 const dom = domHTML(script, contact, user)
 console.log(dom)
```

Comment: The main thing is the script comes from a server it's not hard code, So it this possible to pass script and replace variable

Comment: @FahimMahmudChisti If you add more information about your code we'd be able to help you better.